# Example of a working OWASP Zap script with authenticated scan using API

Tags: python, owasp, zap

Can someone please show a script that is capable of doing the above? I have found a good amount of instruction on the web and tried a lot of different things but still can't get Zap to login to the page to perform a full scan.

The best I get is something like this:

```
 'http://XXX',
 'http://XXX/robots.txt',
 'http://XXX/sitemap.xml',
 'http://XXX/webui',
 'http://XXX/webui/index.html',
 'http://XXX/webui/index.html?Password=ZAP&Username=ZAP',
 'http://XXX/webui/login',
 'http://XXX/webui/login/assets',
 'http://XXX/webui/login/assets/images',
 'http://XXX/webui/login/assets/images/companylogo.png',
 'http://XXX/webui/login/assets/styles',
 'http://XXX/webui/login/assets/styles/login.css',
 'http://XXX/webui/login/login.js',
 'http://XXX/webui/login/redirect.js',
 'http://XXX/webui?Password=ZAP&Username=ZAP'
```

Many thanks

```
from zapv2 import ZAPv2
from random import randint
import socket
zap_ip = 'zap' #name of a Docker container running Zap
target = 'http://example.com'
auth_url = target + "webui/index.html"
scanners = ['90020', '90029']
# authorized Web UI user
username = test
password = test
auth_data = 'password={%password%}&username={%username#%}'
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
zap = ZAPv2(proxies={'http': 'http://' + zap_ip + ':' + str(port),
    'https': 'http://' + zap_ip + ':' + str(port)})
new_context = randint(1, 100000000000)
session = zap.core.session_location
session_name = 'session_1.session' if zap.core.session_location == \
    'session_0.session' else 'session_0.session'
zap.core.new_session(name=session_name)
zap.core.load_session(session_name)
context_id = zap.context.new_context(new_context)
zap.context.include_in_context(new_context, '.*')
zap.ascan.disable_all_scanners()
for scanner in scanners:
    zap.ascan.enable_scanners(scanner)
all_rules = [scanner for scanner in \
    zap.ascan.scanners() if scanner['enabled'] == 'true']
start_url = auth_url if auth_url else target
zap.urlopen(start_url)
auth_method_name = 'formBasedAuthentication'
authmethod_configparams = 'loginUrl=%s&loginRequestData=%s' % (auth_url, auth_data)
authcred_configparams = 'username=%s&password=%s' % (username, password)
zap.authentication.set_authentication_method(contextid=context_id,
    authmethodname=auth_method_name, 
    authmethodconfigparams=authmethod_configparams)
user_id = zap.users.new_user(contextid=context_id, name=username)
zap.users.set_authentication_credentials(contextid=context_id,
    userid=user_id,
    authcredentialsconfigparams=authcred_configparams)
zap.users.set_user_enabled(contextid=context_id, userid=user_id, enabled=True            zap.forcedUser.set_forced_user(context_id, user_id)
zap.forcedUser.set_forced_user_mode_enabled('true')
spider = zap.spider.scan_as_user(url=target, contextid=context_id, 
    userid=user_id, recurse='false')
while (int(zap.spider.status()) < 100):
    time.sleep(2)
zap.ascan.scan(target)
zap.ascan.remove_all_scans()
zap.core.delete_all_alerts()
zap.context.remove_context(new_context)
```

Comment: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-python/tree/master/src/examples

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is, in general, a pain. There are so many different ways authentication can be implemented its really difficult to provide anything other than very generic advice.

However the fact that you've got a URL like 'http://XXX/webui?Password=ZAP&Username=ZAP' implies you have not configured something correctly as these are the default values supplied by the ZAP spider.

If you can supply more details about what your application appears to expect and what you are doing then we should be able to help some more.

Comment: It connects to proxy, creates context, uses form-based auth to perform an active scan - please see the code I added in edits. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So I'd recommend doing the same thing but with the ZAP desktop running locally so you can see exactly whats going on. This FAQ has some good diagnostic suggestions: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQformauth#diagnosing-problems (which dont just apply to form based auth)